# Kivy,[WARNING] [Audio ] Unable to find a loader for </storage/emulated/0/it.mp3>

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Actually i was trying kivy audio and it worked fine on linux but when i made it's apk and tested in android then the app crashes. Here are it's code and logs.

code:-

```
import glob
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

Builder.load_string('''
<hey>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            id:change
            text:"hi"
            on_press:root.yeah()

''')

class hey(RelativeLayout):
    def yeah(self):
        #k = glob.glob("/root/.")
        k=glob.glob('/sdcard/shivam.mp3')
        print(k)
        self.ids.change.text="%s"%k
        self.song=SoundLoader.load('/sdcard/shivam.mp3')
        return self.song.play()




class hello(App):
    def build(self):
        return hey()

hello().run()
```

logs:-

```
10-01 16:36:00.038 23853 24004 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 19)
10-01 16:36:00.038 23853 24004 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
10-01 16:36:00.045 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.kivy.example.audio/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-10-01_0.txt
10-01 16:36:00.045 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
10-01 16:36:00.045 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Aug  7 2017, 20:14:35) 
10-01 16:36:00.045 23853 24004 I python  : [GCC 4.8]
10-01 16:36:00.076 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
10-01 16:36:00.607 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
10-01 16:36:00.643 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
10-01 16:36:00.731 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
10-01 16:36:00.735 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
10-01 16:36:00.769 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
10-01 16:36:00.770 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
10-01 16:36:00.770 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.2 V@145.0 (GIT@I3d52eaf367)>
10-01 16:36:00.772 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
10-01 16:36:00.772 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 506>
10-01 16:36:00.773 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
10-01 16:36:00.774 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
10-01 16:36:00.783 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
10-01 16:36:00.869 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
10-01 16:36:00.874 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
10-01 16:36:00.894 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
10-01 16:36:01.395 23853 24004 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
10-01 16:36:01.396 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
10-01 16:36:01.402 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
10-01 16:36:01.406 23853 24004 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Base        ] Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android presplash.
10-01 16:36:04.487 23853 24004 I python  : ['/sdcard/shivam.mp3']
10-01 16:36:04.537 23853 24004 I python  : [WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for </sdcard/shivam.mp3>
10-01 16:36:04.538 23853 24004 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
10-01 16:36:04.538 23853 24004 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
10-01 16:36:04.539 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 34, in <module>
10-01 16:36:04.541 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
10-01 16:36:04.542 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
10-01 16:36:04.543 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 663, in mainloop
10-01 16:36:04.544 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
10-01 16:36:04.545 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
10-01 16:36:04.546 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
10-01 16:36:04.546 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
10-01 16:36:04.548 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:8191)
10-01 16:36:04.549 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1188, in on_motion
10-01 16:36:04.549 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:8191)
10-01 16:36:04.550 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1204, in on_touch_down
10-01 16:36:04.551 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:8191)
10-01 16:36:04.551 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
10-01 16:36:04.552 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
10-01 16:36:04.552 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:8191)
10-01 16:36:04.553 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
10-01 16:36:04.553 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
10-01 16:36:04.554 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:8191)
10-01 16:36:04.554 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
10-01 16:36:04.555 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:8146)
10-01 16:36:04.555 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:14035)
10-01 16:36:04.555 23853 24004 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1109, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:12816)
10-01 16:36:04.556 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/audio/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
10-01 16:36:04.556 23853 24004 I python  :    File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
10-01 16:36:04.557 23853 24004 I python  :    File "/root/plyer/examples/audio/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 25, in yeah
10-01 16:36:04.557 23853 24004 I python  :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
10-01 16:36:04.600 23853 24004 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

How can i remove this bug? I think here `Soundloader` is not loading the `mp3` file. did somebody tried audio and video for android through kivy before? Need help

Comment: I did not, but i suspect it's going to be easier with `.ogg` instead of `.mp3`, if you can convert.

Comment: @Tshirtman i did the same but for that i need to convert mp3 file to ogg in android. Is there any way(library) that we can convert files in android through python?

Answer (score 0):

Add ffpyplayer in the requirements of your buildozer.spec file. Also in the beginning of your code add the line `os.environ["KIVY_AUDIO"] = "ffpyplayer"`
It worked for me.